# Transliteration words match

Tags: java, dictionary, transliteration

I am making a transliteration in java, as we know there are different combinations of words in the language when written in Roman Script the same thing is with the language I am working on. For that a most appropriate word has to be chosen among all the possible combinations! Thats what I want to do, I want you guys to suggest If i am doing it wrong way, that I think that if I make all the possible combinations and then match them "in a dictionary of my language" to match the most appropriate word and display it, is that a good idea? if not how do I perform it in a better way or whats the closer solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [ICU4J](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) class com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator